# Await for a function to finish not working

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the first function that looks like this:

```
private async checkIsExists(): Promise<Boolean> {
    this.repositoryService.getEntry(this.id)
      .subscribe({
        error: (err) => {
          return false;
        }
      });
    return true;
```

This function should return false if any error occurs, such as a 404.
In the repositoryService i have the getEntry function that looks like this:

```
getEntry(entryId: string) {
    return this.collectionsApi.getEntry(entryId);
  }
```

Which is not an async function
My question would be, how could i make the check function work correctly, at this moment it returns true no matter what, because it doesnt wait for the data to be fetched, i would like to change only this function if possible

Update:
I changed the function and the call to this:

```
  private checkIfShareExists(): Observable<Boolean> {
    return this.repositoryService.getEntry(this.id).pipe(
      catchError(() => of(false)),
      map( () => {
        return true;
      })
    )}

...

this.checkIfShareExists().subscribe(exists => {
      console.log(exists);
    });
```

But it still prints true always, even though the error is thrown

Comment: does it has to be a promise or do can you use an observable instead.

Comment: @HenrikBøgelundLavstsen I can use anything that works, can you show me how to modify to use observable?

Comment: Well you immediately and explicitely `return true`. This function cannot return anything else

Comment: @JeremyThille i updated the question with a new version, but it still prints true always

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `getEntry` is an observable (since you are `subscribe`ing to it) you can use async await if you transform it into a promise:

```
private async checkIsExists(): Promise<Boolean> {
    return await this.repositoryService.getEntry(this.id).toPromise().then(r => true).catch(r => false);
}
```

After this you can use that function inside another async-await block to get your boolean result:

```
async myFunc(){
   var couldGet = await this.myComponent.checkIsExist();
   if(!couldGet) { console.error("sadface.jpg") }
}
```